Confusions about Figure 16.1 in Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds"
In Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds" , page 136 , Lemma 16.1 , it defines a function $f(x)$ to show that function in Figure 16.1. However, it seems the figure for $y=f(x)$ is wrong because $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty^{+}}f(x)=1$. Am I right?
This a question from Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds". I show you the whole context of the question below.


As rough sketches, it's close enough on $[0,1]$. Desmos link

@PrincessEev So, is Figure 16.1 wrong in the book?

I wouldn't say it's wrong enough to matter.

@PrincessEev What do you mean?

Your DESMOS Input has a typo , @PrincessEev , when that gets fixed , the matching is complete.

Munkres wants some "Properties" , while constructing a function.
That construction is using $f(x)$ to generate $g(x)$
We are given 2 graphs.
Is figure 16.1 showing the right $f(x)$ ? YES & NO !
Is figure 16.1 showing the right $g(x)$ ? YES !
Our intuition is that $e^x$ will increase "exponentially" (naturally) , while $e^{-1/x}$ will flatten out to $1$. Here it seems to be increasing "exponentially" , making it seem wrong.
Plotting it out to $(0,10)$ , we can see the intuitive flattening :

Plotting it out to $(0,1)$ , we can see no such flattening :

Plotting it out to $(0,0.1)$ , we can see it increasing "exponentially" :

This is what Munkres has given , which is indeed right !
It just does not match our intuition at the moment !
Munkres has not given the Scale , which adds to the confusion.
Checking out the other figure , we get :

We have nothing wrong there.
IMPORTANT : All Images were generated by Wolfram Alpha Online Tool.

Thank you. It's a great answer.

Thank you again for introducing Wolfram Alpha Online Tool.

There are other tools like DESMOS , PARI/GP , GEOGEBRA

Figure 16.1 is not really wrong, but a bit misleading because it suggests that both parts have the same scaling. Thus one expects that the graph of $f(x)$ is depicted for $x \le 1$. The $y$-axis is not explicitly scaled, but one has $f(1) = e^{-1} = 0.3678...$ which implicitly scales the $y$-axis. $g(x)$ has its maximum at $x = 0.5$, where $g(0,5) = 0.0183...$ which gives another scaling of the $y$-axis. These two scalings are not compatible.
Here is a desmos plot ($f(x)$ in red, $g(x)$ in blue):

Anyway, the purpose of Figure 16.1 is not to give a precise graphical representation of the functions $f, g$, but to explain the idea how to find $\phi$ for $n = 1$ and $Q = [0,1]$. I think Munkres has done this quite neatly.
